# Laravel Many To Many Method Issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a many to many relationship between the models User & Notification.

User Model:

```
public function notifications()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Yeayurdev\Models\Notification', 'notifications_user', 'user_id', 'notification_id')
        ->withPivot('notifier');
}
```

Notification Model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Yeayurdev\Models\User', 'notifications_user', 'notification_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Pivot Table:

```
ID     USER_ID     NOTIFICATION_ID
1         2               1
```

In my view, I retrieve a list of all notifications for a user like so.

```
@foreach (Auth::user()->notifications as $notification)
   {{ $notification->user->username }}
@endforeach
```

The problem is that when I try to get the username of the user with that notifications, I get the error Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$username. "Username" is the column on my users table which is just a string. I don't see where I'm going wrong because if I just do "$notificatin->user" it gives me the collection.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with parentheses `{{ $notification->user()->username }}`?

Comment: Can you add the contents of `$notification->user` to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, the relationship is many-to-many, so $notification->user in your case is returning a collection of User models, NOT a single user. If you need only a first user then just do

```
{{ $notification->user()->first()->username }}
```

If you need to print out all users for every notification, then you will need a loop here to go through all users.

```
@foreach (Auth::user()->notifications as $notification)
    @foreach($notification->user as $notificationUser)
        {{ $notificationUser->username }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I would recommend renaming user() relationship to users() to avoid confusion in the future.

Comment: Yep, I just figured that out. Should've noticed at first when I did $notification->user and viewed the output. Thanks!